# undoing changes to bashrc from terminal

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal

Unfortunately I just overwrote my `.bashrc` with

> `echo "command" > ~/.bashrc`

as opposed to appending via

> `echo "command" >> ~/.bashrc`.

Not a huge throwback as I am newer to working in the terminal. **HOWEVER I AM WONDERING** if it is possible to recover my `.bashrc` before I restart my terminal session!

Is there a location where a session's commands are stored? If so - how can I extract my custom scripts?

Expecting for the worst of news, hoping for the best of news! I'm running an Ubuntu 13.04 box and the session is in Guake Terminal - if that changes things at all.

Comment: `git revert .bashrc` probably won't help now, but I hope this will teach you so that it will work the next time this happens.

Comment: definitely learned my lesson here! thanks for the input!

Comment: :( It. happened with me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't completely recover. But you can partially recover using `set`.

If you run `set` on the same terminal you'll be able to get a whole list of custom scripts and other environment variables set. And in that, it's upto to differentiate the ones that were part of `.bashrc` and others typed on that terminal. But you won't be able to recover the commands which used to be executed as part of bash login.

Comment: This is it! thanks so much. It's a lot to parse through, however this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

For the future you may consider using a version control system such as [git](http://git-scm.com/) or [hg](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) in order to save previous versions of files such as `~/.bashrc`. Then if you happen to do a `>` rather than `>>` in the future you should be able to recover the file back to the point the last time you commited it to the version control.

An example of how to set this up for `git` would be:

```
cd ~
git init
git add ~/.bashrc
git commit -m "Added .bashrc to version control"
# Time goes by...
echo "export FOO=bar" >> ~/.bashrc # Added a new line
git commit -am "Added FOO to .bashrc"
# Time goes by...
echo "export SHEEP=lambs" > ~/.bashrc # Eeek! We've overwritten our file
# Version control to the rescue
git checkout ~/.bashrc # file is restored
echo "export SHEEP=lambs" >> ~/.bashrc # Done correctly this time!
git commit -am "Added SHEEP to .bashrc"
```

Comment: Extremely useful! I'll definitely be doing this from now on

Answer (score 2):

*Assuming you built your `.bashrc` with a bunch of similar `echo` commands and you just want to retrieve them:*

> Is there a location where a session's commands are stored?

If you run `history`, you should be able to retrieve the previous commands.  For more information, see `man history`.

In your case, you might find the output of `history | grep bashrc` useful.

Comment: I think he's looking to restore the contents of `.bashrc`, not find a list of commands he's run from the terminal.

Comment: @chepner Sounds like he just build his `.bashrc` by appending stuff to it with `echo`, though.

Comment: -1 `history` does not contain the commands that used to be in your `.bashrc`.

Comment: @tripleee I didn't say it did.

Answer (score 2):

Cannot be recovered.

I suggest you to type `env` in your terminal to view the most important environment variables (like LD_LIBRARY_PATH, PATH, PYTHONPATH, CLASS_PATH, JAVA_HOME, and so on ...) and add them back into a new .bashrc file.

You can start from a copy of `/etc/skel/.bashrc` as a minimal file.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing the link to an answer in another post which helped me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40214165/13151296
If you only added a few touches to your bashrc, you can use this to get a fresh default bashrc and then add what you need using methods in previous answers of this thread.

> Type the following in your terminal,
>
> /bin/cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/
>
> It will replace your corrupt ~/.bashrc
> with a fresh one. After that you need to source the ~/.bashrc so that
> the change take place immediately, write in terminal,
>
> source ~/.bashrc
>
> or if that does not work you can close the terminal
> and open it again.