# Trouble installing haskell: how to adjust PATH variable to add to a shell config file?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, haskell

I installed Haskell on my MacOS system using ghcup installer. It worked because if I type ghci I am dropped into this interactive shell. However I got this message in the terminal after doing the install:

```
In order to run ghc and cabal, you need to adjust your PATH variable.
You may want to source '/Users/user1/.ghcup/env' in your shell
configuration to do so (e.g. ~/.bashrc).

Detected bash shell on your system...
If you want ghcup to automatically add the required PATH variable to "/Users/user1/.bashrc"
answer with YES, otherwise with NO and press ENTER.

YES
grep: /Users/user1/.bashrc: No such file or directory
```

My shell is bash 3.2 But as you can see, when I typed YES it says there is no such file. How do I find my shell configuration file, or resolve this? I'd like to complete the setup correctly here.
And I have to be honest about my level of knowledge here, I don't truly understand what this is asking exactly. Is the PATH variable 'env'?

Comment: Does the file `/Users/user1/.bashrc` exist on your system ?

Comment: Also, regarding your question about `env` / `PATH` : `PATH` is an environment variable that will include a list of folders. `env` is a command, that will lookup every folders listed in `PATH` and retrieve the programs available

Comment: Yes, it came back as file exists. But ghcup doesn't see it?

Comment: How did you check that ? `cat /Users/user1/.bashrc` ?

Comment: FILE=/Users/user1/.bashrc if test -f "$FILE"; then echo "$FILE exists fi

Comment: When I ran this cat command, I got back: [ -f "/Users/user1/.ghcup/env" ] && source "/Users/user1/.ghcup/env" # ghcup-env
. ~/.ghcup/env

Comment: ok so it's in there? Why is it saying no such file or directory? thanks for your help btw, much appreciate it

Comment: Seems to me that it worked. If  you still can't launch your command, you can have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51876792/why-must-i-source-bashrc-every-time-i-open-terminal-for-aliases-to-work/51877640#51877640. Ortherwise, you're good to go

Comment: very strange why it would return this even thought it worked. Just one last question, should there not be more in this .bashrc file other than just ghcup? I would have thought this is the main bash config file and would have longer list of directories?

Comment: Osx does not provide a default bashrc config. You can take the 2nd answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40206151/how-to-restore-default-bashrc-ubuntu) as inspiration, and copy the code snippet you currently have at the end of it

Comment: wow. no idea how you know all of this! Thanks a mil for your help!

Comment: Just as a followup, I had left this issue down right before I went to sleep and just realised I had entered echo '. ~/.ghcup/env' >> ~/.bashrc just before I crashed. Sorry! I've read that source can do of three things: 'Used to refresh the current shell environment, the source command can also be used in order to import functions into other bash scripts or to run scripts into the current shell environment'. Which one is it in this case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230945/discussion-between-aserre-and-cheznead).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On macOS, `.bashrc` does not exist by default. `ghcup` will create this file, so the command you ran will have worked correctly. However, one of `ghcup`'s subcommands expected to find the file before it was created, and therefore reported that error message. You can safely ignore this.